# Test Android library with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-testing, android-gradle-plugin

What is the correct flow for testing an Android library? My library heavily relies on `android.location` and the Google Play Services fused location provider, so I'd like to be able to test location changes.

After adding the `instrumentTest` folder under `src`, what should I do? The Gradle User Guide [simply says](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing-Android-Libraries) to test the library like a regular app, but since I have no `Activity` how do I instantiate my library classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`InstrumentationTestCase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.html) (and subclasses, depending on your needs).

You can get the `Context` by calling `getInstrumentation().getContext()` inside your test cases.

When using Gradle you just need to place your test classes in `/src/instrumentTest`, and run them by creating an *Android test* Run Configuration. You can also run the tests from the command line: `./gradlew check` (or, one of the variants, such as `connectedCheck` or `connectedInstrumentTest`).

Lastly, you should probably mock out all your external dependencies. You might want to look at some mocking framework such as Mockito, or just do stuff yourself.

Comment: This is a good point towards the right direction. Although, I am having issues with the second part of the question, that is: how can I test a mock location? I am able to use [setMockMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addTestProvider(java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean, int, int)) in an *application* with the permission `ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION`, but setting that into a library manifest or a test manifest leads to a `SecurityException`, as it looks like the permission is not handled - like at all.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just create a simple app that uses your library? You can use Genymotion to test different locations (including altitude): http://www.genymotion.com/